Is it inductor?

When I disassembled the digital audio player, I accidentally damaged one of the components similar to the one I circled and this component is in series with the component I circled and is connected to the 24 MHz crystal, what I want to ask is whether is this an inductor?, If yes, can I replace it with an inductor with a different value?

The picture is too unclear to determine the circuit connections on PCB. If the broken component was identical to the other white component and both connect to the crystal, then they are load capacitors. If that is not a crystal but an oscillator, there is a chance it might be a power supply filter for the oscillator. No, you can't just randomly change a random component there, even with correct about capacitor or inductor, and expect it to work at all or properly.

Looks like a solder problem in photo

inductor with a different value ... what value is the damaged inductor?

It's almost certainly a capacitor in the low to medium picofarad range. Maybe between 4.7 pF and 47 pF. It's possibly connecting the output from the 24 MHz oscillator module to its left to some other circuit. You can sort-of find out by researching an appropriate 24 MHz oscillator module and using a DVM to check that the output pin connects to the capacitor then, you might be able to get away with something like 15 pF but, don't be surprised if it doesn't work entirely how it should.
These things are hard to fix without a schematic but, I can say that it doesn't look like an inductor.
